# How to order a comma-separated list

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

In Oracle, I want to rewrite a column the data like this:

```
2012AName,2019BName,2017DName,2017CName
```

It's a group by many year+Name
order by year desc and name's first char asc after split ','
result like this

```
2012AName,2017CName,2017CDName,2019BName
```

Comment: Do you want the result to be displayed in rows or how ?your description says year desc but output is not ? Could you edit and make it clear.

Comment: thank your for your replay,its a column I want to rewrite

Answer (score 3):

Does this fit to your requirement,

First we split the given string and the aggregate back using `listagg` and the `order by` you want.

```
with input(str)
as
(
select'2012AName,2019BName,2017DName,2017CName' as str 
  from dual
)
select listagg(split,',') 
within group (order by substr(split,1,4),substr(split,5,1))
  from 
(
select regexp_substr(str,'[^,]+', 1, level) split
  from input 
connect by regexp_substr(str, '[^,]+', 1, level) 
 is not null
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much that just what I want Thank you

Comment: @PeteH, you are welcome and you can accept the answer if it resolves your problem. Thank you.